# Vue js 2.6.13 component not rendering

Tags: vue.js

After upgrading vue js from v2.6.12 to v2.6.13 some components don't get render and no warning message or error message in the console. but when I try to downgrade to version 2.6.12, the component successfully render.

Component code that doesn't get render using v2.6.13

```js
<script>
export default {
  props: {
    rules: {
      type: [String, Object],
      default: '',
    },
    name: {
      type: String,
      default: '',
    },
    vid: {
      type: String,
      default: undefined,
    },

    value: {
      type: [String, Number],
      default: '',
    },
    type: {
      type: String,
      default: 'text',
    },
    placeholder: {
      type: String,
      default: '',
    },
    label: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
    autocomplete: {
      type: String,
      default: '',
    },
    disabled: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
    ariaLabel: {
      type: String,
      default: '',
    },
  },

  data: () => ({
    currentValue: '',
  }),

  computed: {
    isRequired() {
      if (this.rules.includes('required')) return true;
      return false;
    },
  },

  watch: {
    value: {
      handler(after) {
        this.currentValue = after;
      },
      immediate: true,
    },
  },

  methods: {
    handleInput() {
      this.$emit('input', this.currentValue);
    },
  },
};
</script>

<template>
  <ValidationProvider
    v-slot="{ errors }"
    tag="div"
    class="form-group"
    :rules="rules"
    :name="name"
    :vid="vid"
  >
    <label
      v-if="label"
      :for="name"
      class="form-label"
    >
      {{ name }}
    </label>

    <input
      :id="name"
      v-model="currentValue"
      :type="type"
      :class="['form-control', { 'is-invalid': errors[0] }]"
      :placeholder="placeholder"
      :autocomplete="autocomplete"
      :disabled="disabled"
      :aria-label="ariaLabel"
      @input="handleInput"
    >
    <span class="invalid-feedback">{{ errors[0] }}</span>

    <small class="form-help">
      <slot name="form-help" />
    </small>
  </ValidationProvider>
</template>
```

The code and try changing the vue version [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-component-2613-5hzzy), why is the component not rendering?

Comment: Can you please show your package.json?. I had a similar problem. I had to update `vue-template-compiler` to the version number of vue.js.

Comment: From what I observe, the ValidationProvider cannot render the div to wrap the elements inside and causing template has more 1 child in runtime. Add the container manually can solve the problem. Here is the demo:  https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-component-2613-forked-it5yd?file=/src/components/HelloInput.vue:1247-1271 But I cannot explain the real reason behind, you may better open an issue on Github and ask them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a regression [introduced in 2.6.13](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/pull/11963) (tracked as [`vuejs/vue` Issue #12102](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/12102)).

It's now fixed in 2.6.14, as seen in this [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/validationprovider-issue-in-2613-fixed-in-2614-oz055).